# Galois descent for etale motivic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology, galois-descent

I am interested in the map from etale motivic cohomology of a smooth and projective variety over a field $K$ to the Galois invariants of etale
motivic cohomology over the algebraic closure $\bar K$:

$$H^i_{et}(X,Z(n))\to H^i_{et}(X\times_K\bar K,Z(n))^G.$$

Does anybody have an example where the cokernel is infinite? (I am mostly interested in local fields or global fields.)

Comment: I have two ideas on this matter; sorry of one or both of them are stupid. So: 1) Can the question be reduced to the study of  etale motivic cohomology with torsion coefficients? 2) Does the latter differ from the corresponding etale cohomology?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko The answer to both your questions is no (but for (1) you can reduce to torsion *and rational* coefficients, the latter of which are pretty much rational algebraic K-theory). The equivalence of torsion étale cohomology and torsion Lichtenbaum cohomology (away from the characteristic of the field, of course) is a theorem by Cisinski and Deglise.

Comment: @DenisNardin The map is an isomorphism with rational coefficients by a transfer argument. But to know it rationally and with torsion coefficients is not enough as the cokernel with integral coefficients can non-trivially map to the kernel for torsion coefficients in the coefficient sequence. Torsion etale motivic cohomology Z/m(n) has been known to agree with etale cohomology with roots of unity coefficients (away from the characteristic) and logarithmic de Rham-Witt coefficients (at the characteristic) long before Cisinki's and Deglise's work.